# Will the entire picture be load while I just read the first few bytes using Apache HTTP Client，Java，Android

Tags: java, android, http, httpclient

I am using Apache HTTP Client to get file stream from url on Android,I want to check header of the stream to determine whether I should load the entire file, to avoid meaningless cost of network resource.
For now, I use the following code the get the inStream and just read the first few bytes from it:

```
response = mClient.execute(method, localcontext);
final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
if (entity != null) {
    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
    byte[] ints = new byte[2];
    instream.read(ints);
}
```

I am wondering if the whole file will be loaded in the above procedure. Should I close the stream explicitly. How?
Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to use **HEAD method**. It simply **returns the http headers** and no actual content or body.

Example ([from official site](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/methods/head.html))

```
 HeadMethod head = new HeadMethod("http://jakarta.apache.org");
        // execute the method and handle any error responses.
        ...
        // Retrieve all the headers.
        Header[] headers = head.getResponseHeaders();
```

Once you have the header, you can check them and then make another GET/POST call accordingly to actually download the contents.

Comment: Sorry but when I say header of the stream I actually means the ahead part of the entity content:P

Comment: I just want to know if I should close the stream after I've read the data I want.

Comment: Yes. Its a stream. So data flowing continuously, the moment you close it, it stops.